# Proving set is dense

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a dense set of real numbers in $[0,1]$. I need to prove that $B=\{na : a \in A, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $[0,\infty)$. This is very intuitive but I fail to prove it. Any tips?

Comment: Given $x\in B$ and $\epsilon>0$, choose $n$ with $x/n<1$. Then choose $y\in A$, with $|y-x/n|<\epsilon/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, expand the definition of what you want to prove. Then work backward to get the other parts (here prefixed by `//`).

Given $x,y \in [0,\infty)$ such that $x<y$:

//... [To use the condition on $A$ we need an interval that fits in $[0,1]$. So what should $n$ be?]

//Let $a \in A$ such that $a \in (x/n,y/n)$.

$n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \in A$ and $na \in (x,y)$.

**Full proof**

Given a dense subset $A$ of $[0,1]$:

Let $B = \{ na : n \in \mathbb{N} \land a \in A \}$.

Given $x,y \in [0,\infty)$ such that $x<y$:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge y$.

Then $0 \le x/n < y/n \le 1$.

Let $a \in A$ such that $a \in (x/n,y/n)$ [because $A$ is dense in $[0,1]$].

Then $na \in B$ and $na \in (x,y)$.

Therefore $B$ is dense in $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Yeah, that's more or less what I did. Given $(x,y)$ we can always find $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>y$ or $1>y/n$ (and then of course $1>y/n>x/n$). Because $A$ is dense we can find $a\in A$ such that $y/n>a>x/n$ or $y>na>x$. $na \in B$ and so $B$ is dense. But I'm not sure about my approach (also, I don't think that I have to specify $n$ in this case).

Comment: @user217919: As long as each statement taken within its context follows logically from the preceding ones, it must be true. To make everything explicit I'll edit my answer to show how one could express your approach formally.

Comment: @user217919: See if it is now convincing to you. It is good that you want to be absolutely sure about your approach! To achieve that, I suggest you create your own method of writing a formal proof that makes the context of each statement as clear as possible. Whether you follow my format does not matter, as long as you are logically convinced yourself.

Comment: @user217919: As for specifying $n$, you can see that it depends on $y$, so it has to be described somehow even if we don't have to explicitly find a value for it. But at least we must verify that such $n$ that we want actually exists, in this case by the Archimedean property.

Comment: yes indeed, I rely on the Archimedean property. Thank you for your answer.